# How to link and open a PDF file to a specific page -- skim / adobe?

Tags: org-mode

**Q**:  How can I create a link in `org-mode` to a specific page of a PDF file, which can be opened (in either Skim or Adobe) with a mouse-click?

```
* My example heading. :tag:
  [[pdf:/path/to/file.pdf#105][My description.]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer is for `Skim` on OSX, and it utilizes `applescript`.  Skim does not have any command-line options to open a PDF file to a specific page, unless it is a forward-search situation dealing with a TeX file and the built-in Skim `displayline` utility.

Example heading in `org-mode`:

```
* My example heading. :tag:
  [[pdf:/path/to/file.pdf#105][My description.]]
```

The code:

```lisp
(require 'org)

(org-add-link-type "pdf" 'org-pdf-open nil)

(defun org-pdf-open (link)
"Where page number is 105, the link should look like:
[[pdf:/path/to/file.pdf#105][My description.]]"
  (let* ((path+line (split-string link "#"))
         (pdf-file (car path+line))
         (base-filename (file-name-nondirectory pdf-file))
         (page (car (cdr path+line)))
         (script
          (format
            "tell document \"%s\" of application \"Skim\" to go to page %s"
            base-filename page))
         (skim-program "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/MacOS/Skim"))
    (set-process-sentinel
      (start-process "skim-process" nil "open" "-a" skim-program pdf-file)
      `(lambda (p e) (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
        (when ,page ;; just in case user wants to omit the page number from the link
          (start-process "goto-page" nil "osascript" "-e" ,script)))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

On OSX (now macOS), you can simply use [`org-mac-link.el`](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-mac-link.html), it supports Skim and Adobe Acrobat Pro. To use, open pdf file in Skim and go to the page you want to link, then type `M-x org-mac-grab-link` from Emacs, it should insert an org link (like the following) at point.

```
[[skim:///Users/xcy/Downloads/calccard.pdf::2][calccard.pdf, p. 2]]
```

then when you click the link, the pdf file will be opened in Skim and goto page 2, no matter if Skim is running.

---

You can get `org-mac-link.el` from

- `org-mac-link` on Melpa
- `org-plus-contrib` on Org Elpa
- Org Mode's git repo

unless you install `org-mac-link` on Melpa via `package.el`, you have to autoload `org-mac-grab-link` etc or require `org-mac-link.el` somewhere by yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the referral to the `org-mac-link` library, which I was unaware of.  It contains some interesting ideas and may become my preferred method in the future, but I would like some time to try it out and see how I like it.  At this time, I am leaning in favor of continuing to use `#` to separate the page number from the path instead of `::` and I like not having to put an extra `//` before the absolute path.  With all that being said, I look forward to playing with the `org-mac-link` library in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use for **evince** on **Linux** (a modified version of lawlist's answer):

```lisp
(org-add-link-type "pdf" 'org-pdf-open nil)

(defun org-pdf-open (link)
  "Where page number is 105, the link should look like:
   [[pdf:/path/to/file.pdf#page=105][My description.]]"
  (let* ((path+page (split-string link "#page="))
         (pdf-file (car path+page))
         (page (car (cdr path+page))))
    (start-process "view-pdf" nil "evince" "--page-index" page pdf-file)))
```